# where I to put file robots.txt?

Tags: web-crawler

I have the domain www.mydomain.com and I set apache mod-rewrite so as to have www.mydomain.com/myappl. 
Where should I place the file robots.txt? thanks!

Comment: BTW: It's robots.txt, not robotx.txt. Fixed that in the post.

Answer (score 2):

The robots.txt must be accessible to clients as http://www.mydomain.com/robots.txt . How to accomplish that depends on your mod-rewrite configuration. Please post the config if you need more help.

Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard for details.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont't have the apache config (policy reason). I asked to be excluded from the "mod-rewrite" the robots and access as you said.

Comment: I don't really see how you're supposed to fix the server config without access to the (full!) config. Just tell that to your client.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ;-) But you can use the [robots checker](http://www.searchenginepromotionhelp.com/m/robots-text-tester/robots-checker.php) to find if your file is accessible. So if you don't know guess where it will be accessible and test it.